# Get Windows key mapping for a Logitech keyboard on OS X

Tags: macos, keyboard-layout, logitech-keyboard

I have Logitech K340 keyboard. Its key mapping is designed for Windows.

It was no problem to get it working on my MacBook. However, special characters which are reachable via ALT key are mapped like on a Mac keyboard.

I'd like to have the keymap as it's printed on the Logitech keyboard. Is there a way to change this to the Logitech (Windows) key mapping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try [Logitech Control Center](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/494/3129) or [USB Overdrive](http://www.usboverdrive.com/USBOverdrive/News.html) to manually remap keys like in [Logitech Setpoint](http://logitech-en-amr.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/14152/section/troubleshoot/crid/434/lt_product_id/6007/tabs/1,3,2,4,5/cl/us,en)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the Logitech Control Center. It doesn't show my K340 keyboard, but as a nice side effect I can now fine tune the settings of my M510 mouse, which makes it much more usefull on the mac.

Answer (score 0):

Use a tool like [Ukelele](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=ukelele) to create your own keyboard layout, matching what Logitech printed on the keys.

Comment: Ukelele prooved not to be usefull in this case, because it only offers to remap keys, found on a standard Mac keyboard. The Logitech Keyboard has a lot mor keys and it's especially this extra keys which are very anoying.

Comment: @BetaRide And that's information which is missing from your question. You wrote that the relevant keys *are mapped*.